# Extra space in a math expression

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Does anyone know why the code below adds an extra space in the math expression below?

The example

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\NewDocumentCommand\withouthspace{m m}{%
    \frac{d#1}{d#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\withhspace{O{0pt} m m}{%
    \frac{d\hspace{#1}#2}{d\hspace{#1}#3}}   % <--- adds extra space


\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \withouthspace{f(x)}{x} \\
        \withhspace{f(x)}{x}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

aaa\hspace{0pt}bbb.          % <--- no extra space

\(aaa\hspace{0pt}bbb\).      % <--- no extra space
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simplify the example to

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput


\begin{document}


$df$ $d\hspace{0pt}f$
\end{document}
```

Which produces

```
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 d
....\kern-1.66667
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.0764
....\mathoff
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 d
....\glue 0.0
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.0764
....\mathoff
```

The 0pt glue inserted in the second case inhibits the font-specified negative kern between d and f

You don't see it in your `ab` example but would in text mode with, say, `Va` which also has a negative kern in `cmr`fonts.

Comment: Is it really a negative kern, or the absence of an italic correction on *d* in math?  (Pedantry alert.  But yes, *d* is treated differently in the `cm` fonts because Knuth believes the differential *d* should be italic, not upright.)

Comment: Thanks. I understand now, I simply turn off the effect of kern when I insert 0pt space :)

Comment: @barbarabeeton well it logs  as `\kern-1.66667`

Comment: Okay.  I'm thinking of the values in the `.tfm` file, not how the processing proceeds.

Comment: @barbarabeeton it's a tfm kern: `(CHARACTER C d
   (CHARWD R 0.520488)
   (CHARHT R 0.694445)
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C Y R 0.055555)
      (KRN C Z R -0.055555)
      (KRN C j R -0.111112)
      (KRN C f R -0.166667)
      (KRN O 177 R 0.166672)
      )
`

Comment: Try it with `$dx(y)$` to get rid of the effect of the "unusual shape of the *f*.

Comment: `dx` is same as `d\hspace{0pt}x` as there is no d-x kern @barbarabeeton

Comment: Okay.  Use two letters totally unrelated to *d*.  The first letter has to be tall.  Try `$Ma$`.  You'll get a kern.

Comment: Interesting discussion! 1) Indeed, if one compares, e.g., `$df$` or even `$dx$` with `$gx, qx, rx, vx, wx$`, it is clear that there is less space after the `$d$` than after the other letters; and the “process” ensures this because `d` has no italic correction in `cmmi10` while `g`, `q`, `r`, `v` and `w` all have. 2) There is the same amount of italic correction after `M` in `$Ma$` and in `$M\hspace{0pt}a$` because... rule 17 of the TeXbook appendix G says so! (hint: `\fontdimen2` is 0 for `cmmi10`).

Comment: To be clear: I agree with @DavidCarlisle that the visible difference between `$df$` and `$d\hspace{0pt}f$` is explained by the absence of a negative d-f kern in the latter. But I also found what @barbarabeeton wrote quite noteworthy, in particular: 1) the italic correction *also* shows as `\kern` in the output of `\showoutput`, and 2) the *d* in maths mode appears to have been designed specially in the CM fonts, materialized by the absence of an italic correction.